# Seamless SSO between central and store system

Tags: identityserver4

I have a two Asp.net core MVC application( i.e. Center system and store system), store system can work online and offline.
Therefore, store system has its own db and uses asp identity for authentication and authorization. Center system uses IDP i.e. identity server 4.

What im trying to achieve is that after login into store system while it is online, if i redirect to center system it should take the store system auth cookie and send it to identity server 4 and result a seamless SSO between central and store system.

Can we achieve flow please suggest how.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t really see a good way to do this. Open Id Connect is a protocol that was designed to handle problems of identity sharing (like this one), so the fact that you’re looking for an out of band method for doing the same thing (except where your sharing information *to* your identity server from a server that doesn’t implement the oidc protocol) seems kind of backward.

The only thing I can safely recommend is making the store system authenticate using the center system by utilizing the open id connect authorization code flow. Either that or converting the store system to implement identityserver4 and allowing the center system to authenticate with external idps (the new store idp in this case).

Comment: In that case, How will  store system manage authentication in offline mode. How do we switch between two authentication scheme.

Comment: What do you mean by offline mode?

Comment: Application should work without internet . Should have its own database and have authentication and authorization mechanism working offline.

Comment: How would the application have it’s ‘own database’ that works offline? Is the database client side??